# Class declaration without static

Tags: c++, variables

I have a `class Queue;`
I have these variables defined in that class...
`int head, tail;`

One of the functions check `if (head==tail)`, however I cannot declare `head` and `tail` to be equal to 0 in that function or else every time i call that function it will reset itself...

How can i declare `head` and `tail` to be equal to 0 without static variables...do i need to make a default constructor?

Comment: Please add punctuation marks if you can, it was difficult to clearly undersatnd your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that in the constructor; more specifically in the *initialization-list* of the constructor!

```
class Queue
{
  int head, tail;
  public:
    Queue() : head(0), tail(0) {}
          // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is called initialization-list!
};
```

In the initializatin-list you can initialize all your variables!

If that looks scary, you can also do this:

```
class Queue
{
  int head, tail;
  public:
    Queue() 
    {
        head = 0;
        tail = 0;
    }
};
```

But first approach is **preferred**, as that is initialization, and the second one is assignment!

Read this FAQ : [Should my constructors use "initialization lists" or "assignment"?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in C++ any non-static variables have to be initialized in a method, and a good choice is the constructor (or perhaps an `init()` method, depending on what you're doing)